# factoring Eigen3 temporaries to improve computation speed

Tags: c++11, optimization, lazy-evaluation, eigen, eigen3

I'm sorry to raise a general question about Eigen3'scheme of optimized computation. Let's imagine we do possess two Eigen3 matrices, M and N. Imagine we need to compute the following:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,3> M;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,3> N;

// here is the computation:
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,3> D = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,3>::Identity() + M;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,3> R = D * N * D.transpose();
```

What I would like to know is: is there a ways to avoid copying the expression I + M into a full matrix (thus a copy), and instead use a lazy-evaluation scheme in such an expression. Hopefully, it would be feasible to write in C++11 something like this instead:

```
auto D = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,3>::Identity() + M;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,3> R = D * N * D.transpose();
```

Normally, D is in this case a compound (potentially complex) template lazy-eval. type, so this normally should solve the problem. Could you correct me if not so ?

In the same order of idea, I would like to do the same with:

```
auto E = <undisclosed_type coma initializer>(
                M,
                Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,3>::Zero());
Eigen::Matrix<double, 6,6> R = E * N * E.transpose();
```

but I do not see how to perform such an optimization. So, if there is a way to optimize this out in term of instruction number in the evaluation process, this could help me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible for the comma initializer thing, though there is a proposal for that: [bug 716](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=716). However, even with such a patch making comma initializer a true expression, we would require more code to make your example efficient. Meanwhile, better do the job yourself by writing:

```
R.topLeftCorner<3,3>() = M * N * M.transpose();
```

Regarding the first example, using `auto` will do the job, but it will be slower because for efficiency reasons, the sub-expression `I+M` will be evaluated within a temporary anyway.